# Create a Row/Detail display with Bootstrap tables

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an ASP.NET application (non-MVC) that uses Bootstrap. I have a page that displays a gridview that uses Bootstrap CSS and it works great. But now I want to add the ability for user to click a particular row (record) and have a detail section open below that record and display some data. I'm really almost looking for a table where each row acts like an accordion panel where I can display the detail data. How can I go about this? I am unable to find any examples of Boostrap tables that display details

Comment: bootstrap just styles your table, you need to write own code for which rows to display. Can be done with some very simple jQuery if the detail rows already exist

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse
Hope it's what you're looking for.

`jsfiddle.net/whytheday/2Dj7Y/11` It's maybe more what you are looking for.

Comment: well yes, that's the general functionality of an accordion. But I have yet to see an example like this that combines it with a Bootrap table

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/whytheday/2Dj7Y/11/
It's maybe more what you are looking for.